# Were there any war movies made during WW2 that were well regarded by front-line American soldiers?

Tags: 20th-century, popular-culture, world-war-two

I've read in a few places that American soldiers during WWII (meaning men who had actually seen combat, not rear echelon troops) preferred light comedy or romance movies to the sanitized propaganda in war movies of the time.

Can anyone give me a counterexample?  I'm looking for a plausible reference to a frontline soldier, or group of frontline soldiers, enjoying a war movie - either because they didn't mind the propaganda, or because the movie was unusually realistic.

Edit:  Sorry, the second paragraph isn't really clear - I'm specifically interested in *American war movies that were made during the war, and the combat soldiers' reaction to them.*

I know a lot of more realistic movies were made after the fact.  Thanks and apologies to everyone who answered before the question was corrected.

Comment: Do you insist on American soldiers/movies?

Comment: It's not clear if you're talking only about movies actually produced during the war, or modern ones (such as those in these answers) are fine.

Comment: @Lohoris Yes, I was wondering the same thing, as movies made during the time would be subject to propaganda, while those later tended to be more realistic after a period. Such as Saving Private Ryan.  The questions notes "of the time" but the answers are for later periods.

Comment: Thanks, guys; I didn't realize how badly I'd phrased that.  Better now, I hope.

Comment: @DVK - yes; it's only for American soldiers that I've seen those references of resenting propaganda movies, and I've seen them in several different places - it seems the feeling was pretty widespread, and I'd like to know if it was universal

Comment: @RoseAmes: Does my edit reflect what you wanted to ask?  If so, I shall delete my answer as it does not answer your question.

Comment: @Sardathrion: 3 answers out of 3 answer a different question, I fear it's not salvageable anymore. Maybe editing the question to reflect the answers, and asking the question again as new, could be a better option.

Comment: @Lohoris: I see your point. That decision should rest with the Rose Ames to be honest.  I am loathed to edit her(?) questions to change its meaning.

Comment: @Sardathrion, yes, the question reflects what I'm looking for now.  Sorry for the confusion - I'm pretty new to this.  Will pay more attention to my phrasing in the future.

Comment: @Lohoris I'm not rephrasing the question to reflect the answers as I'm not sure that a question about modern movies really belongs on a history Q&A site.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Of the war movies made during WWII, American veterans liked the realistic ones:

- The Battle of Midway (1942)
- At the Front (1943)
- Report from the Aleutians (1944)
- With the Marines at Tarawa (1944)
- The Memphis Belle (1944)

On the other hand, the "tough guys" of the time, notably John Wayne and Humphrey Bogart  were not regarded at all among the veterans (this contradicts Tom Au's answer, vide Casablanca).

Source:  Gambone *The greatest generation comes home: the veteran in American society*, 2005, pp. 159-160 
 http://books.google.pl/books?id=7SRZzJUf8cYC&pg=PA159

Comment: Thanks, that looks like a really interesting book.  Does it say specifically that they disliked Casablanca?  It's not my idea of a propaganda war movie - not about soldiers, for one, and the patriotism is mixed with a fair amount of cynicism and humour.

Comment: @Rose Ames no; the book does say explicitly that soldiers disliked Bogart in the war time, but does not mention what appearance (he starred in many films although Casablanca is most known).

Comment: I believe that Bogart and Wayne were not well-regarded because they simply "acted" tough in the movies and men who had seen combat could see through the acting. I think it really bothered both men.

Comment: To follow up, John Wayne was embarassed about it, which helped prompt him to make the ridiculous, so-bad-you-love-it Viet Nam war movie, "The Green Berets".

Answer (score 3):

I found this panel interview discussion on PBS org. The panel included, Speilberg, actors, and a veteren by the name of Judge John Harrison. I will quote a few of his comments below but heres the [link](http://www.pbs.org/newshour/bb/entertainment/july-dec98/ryan_8-3.html).

> PHIL PONCE: As one who was at D-Day on Utah Beach, in your case, was
>   the film's depiction of what it was like, was it accurate, to your
>   mind?
>
> JUDGE JOHN HARRISON: I was off the beach and, of course, the Utah
>   Beach was a much easier beach as far as losses are concerned than
>   Omaha. Omaha, from what I gathered, was a slaughterhouse, and it was
>   beautifully or tragically shown in this picture.

---

> PHIL PONCE: Judge, do you think the movie caught the character of what
>   that experience was like for people at D-Day?
>
> JUDGE JOHN HARRISON: I'm sure it did. It couldn't be more real.

Saving private ryan seems to pull at the emotions of veterens and some examples have been compiled into the book [Now You Know : Reactions After Seeing Saving Private Ryan](http://www.google.com/search?q=Now%20You%20Know%20%3a%20Reactions%20After%20Seeing%20Saving%20Private%20Ryan&sourceid=ie7&rls=com.microsoft%3aen-us%3aIE-SearchBox&ie=&oe=). If you are very curious you may want to check it out.

Comment: That's a well researched answer to a question that I didn't mean to ask :P.  The book looks interesting though.

Answer (score 1):

There are so few relatively realistic American movies about WWII to choose from that it really doesn't make sense to require any hard poll data from veterans.

- [Saving Private Ryan](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120815/) - already mentioned, probably the most epic of all
- [When Trumpets Fade](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0135706/) - very grim, people said it conveys the spirit of the Hurtgen forest battle
- [Letters from Iwo Jima](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0498380/) - Japanese perspective on the battle
- [Flags of Our Fathers](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0418689/) - American perspective on the Iwo Jima battle
- [The Great Raid](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0326905/) - about the Raid at Cabanatuan
- [Thin Red Line](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120863/) - about the Guadalcanal battle
- [A Midnight Clear](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0102443/) - probably not very realistic plot but still in a very historical context (before the Ardennes offensive)
- [Saints and Soldiers](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0373283/) - also not very realistic plot but also very historical context (Ardennes again)
- [The Longest Day](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0056197/) - D-Day (actually I need to yet see this one)
- [Memphis Belle](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0100133/) - the one from 1990 (since my list focuses on more recent cinema)

As to TV, the choice is simple:

- [Band of Brothers](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0185906/) - excellent, includes commentary from veterans
- [The Pacific](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0374463/) - like the above, but in Pacific theater

This list may be expanded as long as I don't have to limit myself to American movies or to WWII.

Comment: THese were made after WWII and not during.

Answer (score 1):

The "classic" movie of World War II was **Casablanca.** It was both a romance AND a war movie.

But mostly it was a "good versus evil" morality play, with the hero, Rick Blaine, "giving up" his former girlfriend (the Ingrid Bergman character) to a resistance fighter for the sake of the war effort, and receiving the friendship of the former "collaborationist," Captain Renault, in return.

Ironically, Hollywood had the same idea as the U.S. Army, that Casablanca was the focal point of World War II (and the movie was rushed into production when the American troops landed there). The Allied victory in North Africa allowed the invasion of the Axis' "soft underbelly" in Italy. An Axis victory there would have allowed them to invade America's "soft underbelly"--in Brazil.

Comment: Sure, but what about war veterans?

Comment: @Lohoris: I believe war veterans liked this. I've seen men of a "certain" age (now dying off) at screenings.

Comment: I think that may have more to do with its ideas as a "classic" than a reflection of it as a war movie.  It is still screened today as a family movie, or as classic cinema, in many places.

Comment: Where do you get the idea that either the US Army or Hollywood thought that Casablanca was the focal point of WWII? The release of the movie, not the production, was rushed when Allied troops landed there. The comment about Brazil is simply odd.

Comment: @DavidNavarre: The Brazil to North Africa invasion route (or vice-versa) is part of American "pop culture," e.g. the board game Risk. I seriously doubt that the military would clued Hollywood on their plans to invade North Africa, so they had to come up with the idea on their own. And here's a plausible Brazil invasion scenario: http://seekingalpha.com/instablog/399221-tom-au/79016-of-winston-churchill-s-contribution-to-the-modern-postwar-world

Comment: @TomAu No, there is no plausible real world scenario for the invasion of Brazil as a way to get to the US. It only makes sense if you play Risk. Far more sensible would be the German's WWI ploy, exposed in the Zimmerman telegram, of using Mexico to get to the US. In 1944, Caribbean islands would have been far more useful than Brazil. If you watch the movie, there's no indication that anyone suspected an American invasion and Hollywood found out when the rest of us did.

Answer (score -2):

There were plenty of British films (if they are any good to you) which were made during the war.e.g.

Went the Day well.

We dive at dawn.

In which we serve.

The Life & Death of Colonel Blimp.

A matter of Life and Death.

Millions Like Us.

Next of Kin.

One of our aircraft is missing.

The first of the few.

Cottage to let.

The Day will dawn

Pimpernel Smith.

The Foreman went to France.

Freedom Radio.

The Way Ahead.

Gasbags.

etc.

You can find a more complete list of war films, with dates of original release, at:
https://www.google.co.uk/search?num=50&site=&source=hp&q=british+films+of+ww2&oq=british+films+of+ww2&gs_l=hp.3..0i22i30l5.2313.8755.0.9219.21.19.0.2.2.0.139.1725.17j2.19.0.msedr...0...1c.1.62.hp..1.20.1628.0.-j2McLf8fOQ

Comment: I suggest you re-read the question.

Comment: @Lohoris The title does not specify that the films have to be American. They appear to be looking for any films which were 'well regarded by American soldiers'. I am certain that most of those films will have been watched by American soldiers at some stage, at least the ones who served in Europe.

Comment: And the point where they would have been weel regarded? You are just listing random movies…

Answer (score -3):

I might add the great documentary 'The War' made by Ken Burns in 2007. A truly magnificent researched piece of work of no less then 14 hours! The imagery is second to none. The stories are deeply moving. It's the ultimate praise for the American soldier who gave up everything to save the world.

Comment: Although this may be a great movie, the OP is looking for movies made *during* WW2.